# Existe uma maneira de abrir uma página HTML dentro de um modal? Como?

Tags: html, angularjs, modal

Tenho o seguinte código que abre uma modal:

```
<div class="uk-modal" id="new_task">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog">
        <div class="uk-modal-header">
            <h3 class="uk-modal-title">{{ newTask.name }}</h3>
        </div>
        <form class="uk-form-stacked">

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Porém eu quero abrir uma outra pagina `.html` dentro desse modal, como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Não sei se é o mais correcto, mas a inclusão de um iframe dentro dessa modal poderia ser uma solução.

Comment: poderia exemplificar com um codigo ?

Comment: Não está claro se você realmente quer abrir uma outra página ou se quer carregar algum conteúdo específico dinamicamente...pois se for o caso basta utilizar algum ajax no jquery ou até mesmo algum outro recurso do Angular, cujo não tenho conhecimento ainda.

Comment: Essa página em html que vai carregar puxa dados do banco?

Comment: sim, é um formulario de cadastro e consulta

Answer (score 1):

O Marconi deu a solução de usar iframe, que não é muito recomendado (é que na verdade, depende da aplicação, se for só esse modal e for coisa simples não tem problema, mas imagina o Facebook por exemplo, ou qualquer sistema na realidade...)
Outra solução é fazer um requisição Ajax, eis com JQuery:

```
//Open Modal
function loadModal(modalPage, modalBox, button){
    $.ajax({
        url: "/modals/" + modalPage,
        async: true,
        success: function(data){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html(data);  
            button.removeAttribute("onclick");  
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("<img src='/images/loading.gif'> Carregando...");
        },
        error: function(){
            $("#" + modalBox + " .modal-body").html("Ocorreu uma erro!");
        }
    });
}
```

Essa é uma função que fiz para um projeto e é bem fácil de usar, nome das variáveis:

**modalPage**: O endereço da página a ser carregada para dentro do modal.

**modalBox**: É o `id` do modal que está sendo carregado, então dá para carregar em diversos modais na página, você adapta ao seu ai.

**button**: Esse é o botão que abre o modal, eu desativo ele para a pessoa não clicar duas vezes.

Bom, é só adaptar ao seu código ai, arruma os endereços, ids e classes de acordo com o seu! Espero que tenha ajudado!

Answer (score 0):

Penso que esta não é a melhor solução, mas cá vai.  No entanto aconselho você a pesquisar por uma solução usando *jQuery*

```html
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/">
        
         <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
 </iframe>
```